# Connect to services running on different Kubernetes clusters at once

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have `db1` running on `cluster1`, and `db2` on `cluster2`. They are not accessible externally, so to connect to db while developing/debugging, I use port-forwarding.

You can only set one cluster as the current/default context at a time, so you can port-forward one db at a time. So instead of connecting to one cluster at a time from my local machine, I start 2 docker containers each pointed to a different cluster, and so I can port-forward both db connections, and then map the container port to a different host port, where I can ultimately access my DB via a client.

```
$ docker run -d --name cluster1 -p 3306:3306 IMAGE
$ docker run -d --name cluster2 -p 3307:3306 IMAGE
```

Inside each container, I am doing

```
$ kubectl port-forward db-0 3306
```

On the host machine, I am trying to connect to `localhost` and the port numbers 3306-3307. I am getting:

`Server not running on the provided host and port.`

Instead of using `-p 3306:3306` with the `docker run` command above, I also tried `--expose 3306` and then connect using the container IP which I get using `docker inspect` and port 3306, but that didn't work either.

Is there anything I am missing? I am keen to know if there's any alternate way of archiving what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: It is most likely due to the fact that kubectl by dafault binds to local interface. To make it accessible from outside of container try using `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0`

Comment: thanks but that didn't work.

Comment: actually after checking again, that worked! :) wondering if there's a better way of doing what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP mentioned in comments, my suggestion worked so I decided to post it as the answer with complete explaination.

---

kubectl by default binds to local interface and therefore can be accessed only using localhost ip (127.0.0.1).

```
$ kubectl port-forward <podname> 8080:8080 &
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080

$ ss -lnt | grep 8080
State      Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128         127.0.0.1:8080                   *:*
```

To make it accessible from outside of container you need to use `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0`. This will bind to all interfaces.

```
$ kubectl port-forward <podname> 8080:8080 --address 0.0.0.0 &
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:8080 -> 8080

$ ss -lnt | grep 8080
State      Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                 *:8080                   *:*
```